# Pandas split column with inconsistent data and inconsistent columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need some help with pandas, I'm trying to clean up csv files. I have three types of CSV

1. correct and expected csv

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 |

2. type one clumped

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 400 | NaN | 500 |

3. type two clumped

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 400 500 | NaN |

I'm trying to correct the csv 2 and 3 so that it will become like csv 1

Code

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


dir = r'D:\csv_files'

file_list = glob.glob(dir +'/*.csv')
files = []
for filename in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
    split = df.pop(2).str.split(' ', expand=True)
    df.join(split, how='right', lsuffix = '_left', rsuffix = '_right')
    print(df)
```

output:

```
  0    1   2   3   4
0 100 200 300 400 500

  0    1   3   4
0 100 200 NaN 500

  0    3
0 100 NaN
```

Goal:

```
   0   1   2   3   4
0 100 200 300 400 500

   0   1   2   3   4
0 100 200 300 400 500

   0   1   2   3   4
0 100 200 300 400 500
```

I printed out the `split` and it's correct, however, I'm unable to find how can I put it back into the main data frame.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor **and add several lines** as this will affect the process. Also provide the raw content of the csv files.

Comment: You can use multiple separator to read your files. Try something like: `pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=r'[, ]', engine='python')`

Comment: Please add the original CSV rows (in text format with the commas/spaces preserved) to your question. This would make it easier to come up with a possible workaround

Comment: @mozway 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SBsSWk-EYBoECYeXKmY7BAg-sAjQ65ke/view) here are the csv samples

Comment: @MartinEvans I provided the samples above, thank you!

Comment: @Corralien I have tried your suggestion but still facing some errors, still working on it tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to pre-parse the data using a standard Python `csv.reader()`. This could be used to split up any 'clumped' values and then flatten them back into a single list.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd    
from itertools import chain
import glob
import csv

data = []

for fn in glob.glob('rate*.csv'):
    with open(fn) as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        
        for row in csv_input:
            values = chain.from_iterable(value.split(' ') for value in row[2:] if value)
            data.append([row[0], row[1], *values])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=range(6))
print(df)
```

This would give you a dataframe starting:

```
                         0                                  1     2     3     4     5
0               Montserrat                            Manzini     6     6     5     6
1               Madagascar                           San Juan    10     4     9     8
2                 Botswana                             Tehran     2    10     9    10
3     Syrian Arab Republic                          Fairbanks     2     4     9     2
4                   Guinea                       Punta Arenas     5     1     6     3
```